# What happens when a class power is lost and then gained again from another source?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

Example: a character has access to the smite ability from class A that he then has to lose to gain another ability (like a feat).
He then takes a level in class B that also gives smite.
Can he use smite now?

Comment: It would help, if you could be a bit more precise: from which class did the character gain the smite ability and for what reason did the character lose it?

Comment: Yeah, losing an ability as you describe is _very_ rare, and I can’t think of any examples of that at all for smite, which makes me suspect you’ve misread something. (I could, of course, have missed or forgotten something, though.)

Answer (score 2):

In the entire game, the only instance I can think of where you are prevented from gaining something even from other classes is the hit-and-run tactics alternate class feature for fighter:

> **Replaces:** By selecting the hit-and-run tactics alternative class feature, you give up proficiency with heavy armor and tower shields, even if you have those proficiencies from another class. You can’t gain either of those proficiencies by multiclassing later, but you can gain them by selecting the appropriate feats.

<sup>(*Drow of the Underdark*, hit-and-run tactics alternate fighter class feature, pg. 58)</sup>

It is quite common for alternate class features to replace something from the class in question—say, the heavy armor and tower shield proficiencies of the fighter class—but in all other cases, you can just get those somewhere else. Hit-and-run tactics is the **only** time you are prevented from gaining it from other classes. Even some class features that certainly sound absolute—for example, the specialist wizard’s “spells of the prohibited school are not available to the wizard”—are [actually not if you multiclass](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/19729/4563). You really need explicit text saying that something affects all classes.

Feats don’t usually replace things at all. Pretty much ever, actually. But in any event, unless something has wording like hit-and-run tactics—and I’m pretty sure nothing else does—you can always pick up whatever you’re missing elsewhere.

The only feat I can think of that has anything to do with giving up smite is From Smite to Song (*Champions of Valor*, pg. 29), but that allows you to use 1 use of your smite ability to instead use inspire courage as a bard. You can still use your smite ability normally, instead of using it for inspire courage, if you like. From Smite to Song provides a new option for those daily smite uses, but does not prevent you from using the original option.

Answer (score 1):

Each class' smite ability is considered separate by default, and should have no bearing on the other.

If *Smite B* instructs you to use *Class A's level* as part of its calculations, you have *Smite B* only.

If *Smite B* augments *Smite A* like in a prestige class, and *Smite A* is no longer available, then you can use neither until *Smite A* is restored.

Without knowing the two classes and levels involved, I cannot be more specific but hope the above helps.