# I want to build a Spellslinger

Tags: pathfinder-1e, pathfinder-society, firearms

I recently got a Spellslinger boon in PFS, so I set out to build one. As Spellslingers give up *FOUR* whooping Schools plus their Arcane Bond to get their Arcane Gun ability, I thought to build a blaster caster.

So, I need *at least* Precise Shot to cast through the gun, which means either two feats, or a dip in Far Strike Unchained Monk (good for +1 BAB, Improved Unarmed Strike and saves, though), and I also need Rapid Reload if I expect to be able to shoot and move, so that's one more feat.

On top of that, I also need to take usual feats such as Spell Focus: Evocation, Mage's Tattoo: Evocation, Greater Spell Focus: Evocation, and some metamagics, for instance Dazing Spell, Reach Spell or Rime Spell.

I had been eyeing Crossblooded Sorcerer to get the Marid and Draconic (White) bloodlines, so I can switch any blast spell to cold damage for Rime Spell cheesing, but progressing as a Crossblooded Sorcerer with a dip on Far Strike Monk is horrid since I get 2nd level spells at level 6.

I also looked at progressing as a Blood Arcanist, since I would be able to get one Bloodline, presumably Arcane, for Arcane Bonding my gun so I can upgrade it at half price (gun enhancement bonus is *VERY* important for Spellslingers).

Lastly, I also thought to progress as a Druidslinger, as the druid is a full caster (which wouldn't penalize me with *another* level of caster progression delay, as Sorcerer or Arcanist would) and I hear they have pretty good Evocation spells.

Eldritch Archer Magus is not on the table, as though I would love to build one, it's banned in PFS.

What would the best class for me to progress as? How can I be an effective blaster caster through my gun?

Please, refer only to PFS-legal material.

Comment: Some potentially useful related questions, which may help you refine this one for re-opening (or eliminate the need to re-open if they answer your questions): [How can I build a caster who fires spells through their guns, or magic-amplified bullets?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/28743/4563), to which spellslinger is *an* answer; [Sword + Pistol Magus](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/77446/4563), which also leverages spellslinger; [What Wizard schools are best to specialize in? Which schools are best to sacrifice?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/19557/4563), but note it is 3.5-based.

Comment: Yeah - "what is best" is usually too vague for us to answer without some more specifications...