# Early entry into mindbender prestige class

Tags: dnd-3.5e, optimization, prestige-class, caster-level

This splits from my previous question: [Increasing multiclass cleric/wizard caster levels](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/105787/increasing-multiclass-cleric-wizard-caster-levels)

This time I'm interested in the fastest way to enter mindbender prestige class as a wizard (or cleric 1/wizard X, if it helps). Plain and straight. You may use any number of feats, alternative class features, flaws, traits, etc. the character of a given level may have. You have an amount of money appropriate to wealth-by-level guidelines. But if it is neccessary it is OK to use additional 1000 or two worth of gold pieces.

I'm not too interested in qualifying through non-permanent things like buying spellcasting servises to make 13 level sorcerer cast Create Magic Tattoo on you  and leveling up "while the spell persists". Probable similar things should be you last resort - if it is the only way, than fine answer should of course adress it.

For this question's sake, "Arcane caster level 5th" prerequisite isn't fulfilled by something rising your caster level for one certain spell or a group of spells (like fire spells or spells from divination subschool) only.

I also urge you to avoid completely broken stuff like Pun-Pun. This includes (but doesn't limited to, I'm afraid) any infinite loops. High power build is OK, but something that no one sane will obviously allow in any real game is off. I know this bit is tricky, but I can't find better definition for my request. Hope it is obvious enough.

I'm asking of pure curiosity for now, if it is of interest for someone.

Comment: So... how does early-entry PunPun not qualify?

Comment: You can do it as a level 1 wizard.  Then you can set your levels to 'yes'.  This includes Wiz 1/Mindbender 1.  Or just Mindbender 1, but that would not meet your criteria. (you can lose levels by energy draining yourself after adding extra HD, or via retraining, and gain any level you meet the prereqs for for 0 XP and 0 days training when you are ECL 0)

Comment: How has the term *arcane caster level* been defined by the DM? That is, is being able to cast a lone arcane spell with a [caster level](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/glossary&term=Glossary_dnd_casterlevel&alpha=C) of 5 sufficient to meet the prestige class's requirements *or* must the creature be able to cast *all* its arcane spells at caster level 5? (I can have the requirements met at level 1 if it's the former, but that latter is *far* harder!)

Comment: @HeyICanChan It's maybe not all spells, but spells which aren't affected by some other caster level altering stuff that affects only certain spells. Default caster level or something like this.

Comment: So it's up to the DM's Mk. I Eyeball to approve each individual scheme? I'm not entirely sure that's fair to answers other than TDW's. Could you confirm a definition with the GM and edit the question with the definition? Otherwise, I'm gonna have to vote to put this on hold as *unclear what [your DM's] asking.*

Comment: @HeyICanChan Am I that much unclear?.. There is no DM, it is theorethical question. If it's +1 CL for conjuration spells only, or fire spells only, or with Dominate Person only it won't work. If its +1 CL for wizard spellcasting or plain +1 to CL it will work.

Comment: That I can get behind.  Sorry for sounding sharp.

Comment: @HeyICanChan I'm also didn't wanted to "sound" harsh or something. My apologies if I did. Just thought there was a common agreement, what satisfies such prerequisites.

Comment: TIL using the Caster Level as PrC requirement instead of the usual "casting spells of X level" seems to be much harder to circumvent.

Comment: Does “fastest” mean fewest xp or fewest non-mind bender levels?

Comment: @fectin-freemonica I'm not entirely sure why are those things separate. LA and RHD are also non-mind bender "levels", for example. So I don't really know. Maybe post your answer and see what it results in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## The easy part: skills and spells…

A typical wizard or sorcerer doesn't have as class skills the skills Bluff, Diplomacy, Intimidate, and Sense Motive. This usually delays the creature's entry into the prestige class mindbender (*Complete Arcane* 54-6) to at least character level 5 because of the maximum ranks that can be put into [cross-class skills](http://dndsrd.net/skills.html#skill-ranks).

The easiest way for a creature to meet this requirement early is to gain the class feature [**social proficiency**](http://dndsrd.net/unearthedSpecialist.html#social-proficiency) (*Unearthed Arcana* 61) the creature must be a specialist wizard—an enchanter—, and the creature "does not gain bonus feats for advancing as a wizard." Ask the DM if this means the creature also doesn't gain at level 1—like a typical wizard does—the bonus feat [Scribe Scroll](http://dndsrd.net/featsAll.html#scribe-scroll) (*Player's Handbook* 99-100). This DM thinks the creature *would* still gain the bonus feat Scribe Scroll based on the way the ability's written, but confirm with your DM that it's legit that the creature'll essentially be getting something for nothing.

Among other benefits, the special ability social proficiency has the creature "[a]dd the following skills to [its] list of [specialist] wizard class skills: Bluff, Diplomacy, Gather Information, Intimidate, and Sense Motive." Yes, the skill Gather Information is there, too, because why not, right?

Anyway, with the special ability social proficiency the creature—if a human enchanter with at least Intelligence 12—can meet the skill rank requirements of the prestige class mindbender at level 1. Note that the *Unearthed Arcana* section in which it appears is called Specialist Wizard Variants, and the special ability is supposed to be used—along with the others for enchanters and for other specialist wizards—by the DM to customize the campaign setting and not really as artifacts available generally. I can't imagine most DM's having a problem with this, but aiming for early entry shenanigans means even the smallest flaw might ruin the plan.

Alternatively, the feats Academy Graduate ([*Savage Tide Player’s Guide*](https://paizo.com/dungeonissues/SavageTide/SavageTide_HR.pdf) 8) and Flexible Mind (*Dragon* #326 80) combined can make all the necessary skills always class skills (plus another skill the creature picks—likely the skill Use Magic Device). This also allows meeting the prestige class's skill requirements at level 1 (or at level 2 under some readings of the feat Flexible Mind). (The feat Able Learner (*Races of Destiny* 150) isn't useful here; it's benefit says, "The maximum number of ranks you can purchase in a cross-class skill remains the same.")

### …And the hard part: *arcane caster level 5th*

While there are undoubtedly other ways to meet the mindbender requirement *Arcane caster level 5th*, no *easy* method of early entry withstands serious scrutiny given the question's binds. Folks have been hunting through official texts for years in attempts to raise artificially a creature's caster level so as to meet prestige class requirements early, from the now defunct Wizards of the Coast's forums archived [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130519043611/http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/19872350/Raising_Caster_Level), to *EN World*'s forums [here](http://www.enworld.org/forum/showthread.php?59075-Sources-of-Bonuses-to-Caster-Level), to *RPG Net*'s forums [here](https://forum.rpg.net/showthread.php?528788-3-X-I-m-looking-for-ways-to-boost-my-caster-level), and repeatedly—over and over again, even—on the *Giant in the Playground* forums, searched for convenience [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=caster%20level%20boosts%203.5%20site:www.giantitp.com&rlz=1C1AOHY_enUS709US709&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj5576zxfzVAhVBj1QKHSe7DpcQrQIIMCgEMAA).

The constant is the [*ioun stone*](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsWI.html#ioun-stones) (orange prism) (*Dungeon Master's Guide* 260-1) (30,000 gp; 0 lbs.). Everything else—when subjected to the strictest reading—fails the question's test of, essentially, needing the arcane caster level increase to persist all the time forever.<sup>1</sup>

For example, the *ring of arcane might* (*Magic Item Compendium* 121-2) (20,000 gp; 0 lbs.)—the *ioun stone* (orange prism)'s closest competitor— specifies that its +1 bonus to the wearer's caster level applies only "for the purpose of spell penetration checks, caster level checks, and all level-based variables of any arcane spells [the wearer] cast[s]," that last part being the sticking point. So, rather than applying *in general*, using a *really* strict reading the caster level bonus of the *ring* applies *only* when actually *casting* spells and *not* when, for example, sleeping, making it situational therefore inapplicable. (Note that this DM and player doesn't encourage that the *ring* be read this way generally; it's read this way here deliberately to demonstrate the question's restrictions.)

Feats that increase caster level are usually even more specific in that they'll typically increase the feat's possessor's caster level for spells of a specific school of magic, spells possessing a a specific descriptor, spells cast while in a certain place or during a certain time, or even spells of a specific name. None of these feats allow the creature to meet that the prestige class requirement more quickly given the question's binds.

Entering the prestige class mindbender any sooner than as a level 4 arcane caster by acquiring early—nearly 25,000 gp early, in fact—the *ioun stone* (orange prism), is, I think, given those binds, impossible.

#### Last resort

What remains then is the question's last resort: meeting the *arcane caster level 5th* requirement of the prestige class mindbender through temporary means. The easiest and earliest way is by employing the standard [*strand of prayer beads*](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsWI.html#strand-of-prayer-beads) (*DMG* 267-8) (25,800 gp; 0 lbs.)… perhaps absent the *bead of healing* and the *bead of smiting*. The creature may have to borrow a standard *strand* from a church if the creature can't get for free a standard *strand* with only the *bead of karma*.<sup>2</sup>

To use this method, the creature gets within a hairsbreadth of the XP required for level 2, cautiously acquires the standard *strand*, carefully constructs a CR ½ booby trap (*Dungeon Master's Guide II* 41) (50 gp or less; trap)—I recommend the alarm booby trap—, and succeeds on a [Use Magic Device](http://dndsrd.net/skillsAll.html#use-magic-device) skill check to emulate the class feature spells of a level 1 cleric (DC 21), convincing the the *bead of karma* to activate. For 10 min. the "[w]earer casts his spells at +4 caster level," the *bead* not caring if the spells are arcane or divine. Then, before 10 min. have passed, the creature encounters the booby trap, earns its 150 XP, and cackles maniacally as it takes its first step along the path of the prestige class mindbender.

Of course, gaming XP gain in such a fashion is, I think, generally frowned upon, and the DM must still be convinced that the *bead of karma*'s effect is sufficient to count as increasing the creature's arcane caster level from 1st—because the creature's *still* an enchanter—to 5th for this purpose, but if the perhaps-too-open-minded DM's been convinced to go this far already, convincing him of that, too, should be fairly easy.

#### The other, even shadier way: play a race with a spell-like ability

The prestige class mindbender's actual requirement says, "Spells or Spell-Like Abilities: Arcane caster level 5th." Thus a creature with a spell-like ability that can be employed as a level 5 wizard may be able to meet this class's requirement. For example, a [duergar](http://dndsrd.net/monstersDrtoDw.html#duergar-dwarf) (*Monster Manual* 91, 92) can use as spell-like abilities 1/day each effects like *enlarge person* and *invisibility* with a caster level of twice its character level (min. 3). By level 3 (or 4 with its Level Adjustment +1), it sort of meets the mindbender requirement. I say *sort of* because the DM must agree that such a creature's effective *arcane caster level* for its spell-like abilities is 5th instead of just its *caster level* for its spell-like abilities being 5th. This will likely be difficult: this DM supposes that the inclusion in the mindbender requirements of the *charm* invocation means the class's authors wanted to open up the class more easily to warlocks—that *also* appear in *Complete Arcane* (5-8) and that actually *have* an arcane spellaster level for their spell-like abilities—rather than opening the class even wider to, for example, bald, joyless gray dwarves.

---

<sup>**1**</sup> The effects of multiple *ioun stones* (orange prism) don't stack according to the *FAQ* (62). [Make of that what you will.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/60044/8610)
<sup>**2**</sup> The *Dungeon Master's Guide* (2003) says to reduce the price of a standard *strand of prayer beads* by 9,000 gp if it's missing the *bead of healing* and by another 16,800 gp if it's missing the *bead of smiting*, hence a net cost of 0 gp for a standard *strand* with only a *bead of karma*. The *Dungeon Master's Guide* (2012) stealth erratas the price of the standard *strand of prayer beads* to 45,800 gp, so that a standard *strand* that has remaining only the *bead of karma* has a price of 20,000 gp.

Comment: I’m pretty sure that the racial SLA approach fails explicitly; see *Complete Arcane* where it talks about how the warlock’s caster level for invocations (which are spell-like abilities) is specifically arcane; it will, I believe, state that most spell-like ability caster levels are neither arcane nor divine. Certainly, the lack of such a statement for those abilities is already enough anyway. The mindbender requirement is for the sake of warlocks, and maybe (can’t recall) dragonfire adepts. I don’t think any other spell-like ability caster levels are called out as arcane.

Comment: @KRyan I didn't like that section either, relying as it does on an extremely shady reading, but spell-like abilities in *Complete Arcane* don't seem to seem to mention what you're remembering, and [core doesn't say that](http://dndsrd.net/abilitiesAndConditions.html#spell-like-abilities) either. I'll happily delete the section if that reference can be found. Seriously, I remember it, too, and I'd like that section gone; it makes me uncomfortable.

Comment: @KRyan As it is basically your answer on linked question what inspired me to ask this question, I'd like to know if you are aware of something beyond this answer. Because as is it looks like there is no sure way to accomplish the task. There is currently no DM who can disallow such an entry, but I know at lest one or two DMs who would disallow it (through Bead of Karma) be it in their games.

Comment: @annoyingimp Pretty much every DM shouldn’t allow entry into mindbender early, because early-entry is pretty high-scale abuse not appropriate for actual games. There could easily be exceptions out there, but a free 100’ telepathy is not one of them. Anyway, inspire greatness + Practiced Spellcaster probably gets you another +2 over *orange ioun stone*, so that’s qualifying at 2nd (to take the first level at 3rd). Not sure if another +1 can be found; probably.

Comment: @KRyan Thanks for the reply. While it is highly unlikely one can have inspire greatness affecting him for realy long periods of time (say a week) it is probably still possible, not sure if it is better then recasting of magic tatoo every day, though... but I got the point.

Comment: @annoyingimp The traditional answer to making sure you have inspire greatness on at the time is to have a warforged or undead bard just perform it continuously until you level up (3.5 bards are limited by the number of separate performances per day, but there is no maximum duration of any single performance and warforged or undead don’t need to sleep). The real trick is finding a 9th-level warforged or undead bard willing to follow around your 2nd-level butt.

Answer (score 1):

## Wizard 1/Mindbender 1/whatever 1

Start as a Wizard. You will need to select charm as one of your spells, and have at least 14 intelligence. Max out each of the required skills.

Pick your favorite 4HD animal. I like dinosaurs, so lets use deinonychus. Any 4HD animal is workable, but a neutral or evil one is easier. Find a were-deinonychus and spar with him until you catch lycanthropy. With your shiny new dinosaur HD, max out the four skills, and take the Practiced Spellcaster feat.

Gain a giant pile of xp and level up, taking Mindbender. You are now a wizard 1/animal 4/Mindbender 1.

Get your lycanthropy cured: remove curse or break enchantment during one of the three days of the full moon. After receiving the spell, succeed on a DC 20 Will save to break the curse.

You are now wizard 1/Mindbender 1. Depending how your DM thinks xp works, you probably immediately gain an additional level and also have your xp set to 5999.

Comment: Well, it seems more or less OK from RAW perspective, so here is your +1. Also, looks mostly unworkable in most real compaigns. Still, thank you!

Comment: Depends what you’re trying to do, which is why I asked about levels vs. xp. If you’re starting at 12th level, do this + thought bottle to start off only a few xp behind. Or use dead-werewolf tricks to catch up. Etc.

Answer (score 0):

The spells should not even need mention: you can get those on your first Wizard level, no questions asked.

The skllls required are the easiest to attain: one simply becomes an Enchanter  and takes social profieciency (Unearthed Arcana). Alternatively, with your cleric dip, you could take the Dragon and Pact domains (not an unlikely combination) and the Apprentive(entertainer) feat (DMG2).

The hard part will be blowing up your caster level. My favored method is Reserves of Strength (feat from Dragonlance Campaign Setting) which in return for up to 3 stun turns will increase your caster level by an equal amount, and allows you to break the caps of spells that would normally be capped by caster level. It does require Iron Will as a prerequisite, so you'd need flaws to take this early enough for it to matter (Cleric or no cleric).

This gives us at worst an entry at lv 3, but can we do better? Absolutely. The Primitive Caster feat (Frustburn) will allow you to raise the caster level of spells by supplying the components (material, vocal, somatic) they normally would not use and raise your caster level for that spell by +1 each.

This means that with flaws (or as a human with one flaw) an Enchanter 1 / Mindbender X is entirely possible: Iron Will, Reserves of Strength, Primitive Caster.

Comment: I appreciate your participation, but I'm not sure how do Reserves of Strength and Primitive Caster qualify one for the prs. Both increase your **effective** caster level for one particular casting only. At best, to make it work character should probably level up mid-casting.

Comment: @annoyingimp I suppose it depends on how you interpret PrC prerequisites. In most games I've been in they are abilities you have to exhibit to existing members of the class, in which case it being possible for every spell you cast or all the time is really the same thing.